# Javascript/jQuery: Make second file input button visible only after first file input button has selected a file

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

So I have two HTML input buttons

```
    <input type="file" id="filename" name="filename" />
    <input type="file" id="csvfile" name="csvfile" />
```

Both files are to have .csv files to be uploaded to them. My question is, how do I hide the button `csvfile`(the second input button) on load, and then only let it become visible after an input file have been selected from the first input button `filename`? also should i put the codes in the method below or outside of it?

```
   $(document).ready(function () {
            // map and variables initialization

            // first input button
            $("#filename").change(function (e) {
               // codes and workings   
            });

            // second input button
            $("#csvfile").change(function (e) {
              // codes and workings
            });    
        });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply make it hidden and use jQuery `show()`:

```js
$("#filename").change(function (e) {
  if (this.files.length > 0) {
    $("#csvfile").show();
  } else {
    $("#csvfile").hide();
  }
});

$("#csvfile").change(function (e) {
  
});
```

```css
#csvfile {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div style="background-color: #DDDDDD;">
  File 1: <input type="file" id="filename" name="filename" />
</div>
<div style="background-color: #BBBBBB;">
  File 2: <input type="file" id="csvfile" name="csvfile" />
</div>
```

It is just a minimal working example. You may add any other checks like file type or size; or hide the whole `div` instead of `input`. It's up to your design :)

Comment: I guess you need conditions too as user may unselect selected file :)

Comment: @RayonDabre Thanks, I was thinking about it, but decided to leave a minimal working example. Now, it is working.

Comment: Thank you! Managed to get it workin with your codes. Appreciate your help!

Answer (score 2):

You could do this with CSS and no JavaScript

HTML:

```
  <input type="file" id="filename" required name="filename" />
  <input type="file" id="csvfile" name="csvfile" />
```

CSS:

```
#csvfile { display: none }
#filename:valid + #csvfile { display: block }
```

Here it is in JS Fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/zxjm94hz/

Comment: Explain a bit about `:valid` Nice answer!

Comment: When you add the "required" attribute to the first input field, you are telling the form that that field must have something seleted. So therefore if nothing is selected in #filename then it is considered "invalid" and once a file is selected then it is considered "valid".

Comment: thanks, this works as well! sadly i can't accept both answers. appreciate your help too though!